# How to add a comma after each byte read from a file and write the byte and the comma to another file?

Tags: java, io

I have a text file that contains only numbers and I want to copy those numbers from that file to another one and to put a comma after each digit.

I have tried to write another byte that represents the comma in ASCII after each byte read and rewritten from the file to the other one, but it seems to override it or being added to it.
Trying to fix this problem I have used `flush()` but the nothing changes.

```java
BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutputStream output = null;
try {
  // inPath & outPath are already defined
  input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inpath));
  output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outPath));

  int c;
  while ((c = input.read()) != -1) {
    if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {  // making sure that the byte is a number
      output.write(c);
      output.write(44);  // 44 is the decimal representation of the comma (,)
    }
  }
} finally {
  if (input != null) {
    input.close();
  }
  if (output != null) {
    output.close();
  }
}
```

if I have numbers like this in the first file:

```
123456789
```

I expect to see them in the other file like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

but I'm seeing things like this:

```
ⰱⰲⰳⰴⰵⰶⰷⰸⰹ
```

Comment: what is `out`?? and is this really not working or is it the way you are checking the result (text editor)?

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger Guess it is expected to be 'output'. The code should work but it puts comma after the last digit. Not sure if the question would be useful for community.

Comment: It looks like the underlying issue is that you should be reading characters, not bytes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes thank you, I tried this and it works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```java
Files.write(Paths.get("e:/numbersSeparated.txt"),
    new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("e:/numbers.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .replaceAll(".(?!$)", "$0,").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is happening and the new file now contains 15 commas between each digit.

Comment: @Omar Mohamed Khallaf As far as I understand your request you need to separate every single digit with comma. Right? So what is wrong? Does it work as expected? If no - pls post the initial file content and needed result.

Comment: After writing a long comment I tried again and every thing worked fined thank you.

Comment: But can you tell me what is the problem with `out.write(44);` after `out.write(c);` it seems that they affect each other.

Comment: @Omar Mohamed Khallaf
Your code is pretty fine except of variable name out. 
1. The actual name is output. If it is not just a misspelling pls check it. 2. No need to put comma after the last digit.
3. No need to invoke  flush() in your case because it is invoked in close() method.

Comment: 1- Yes it's just a misspelling
2- I know this was going to be my next problem
3- I thought I will write the byte that had been read and flushing will allow me to write a new byte, I'm still learning about IO and still wondering why it didn't work although `output.write(44);` writes commas to the output file.

Comment: As @Carlos Heuberger said please check text editor encoding.
Put System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(c)); before output.write(c); to make sure it is ok.
You need to get output like in the bottom panel https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Azm.png

Comment: `output.write(c);` alone has no problems but when I add`output.write(44);` the output is like this `ⰱⰲⰳⰴⰵⰶⰷⰸⰹ`

Comment: @Omar Mohamed Khallaf The issue is still presented?
Again - your code is fine. I guess, the string ⰱⰲⰳⰴⰵⰶⰷⰸⰹ is not about the code but environment (Text editor, Arabic encoding, OS, etc. ). Let's check it? Please open your buggy file (outPath) and source file (inpath) in some hexeditor and post content here (we need bytes representation of input you try to read).

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I don't know exactly what happened but I have updated eclipse yesterday and wrote the same code again today and it works so I think you are right, it may be about the environment but I don't know what exactly is the problem to fix it, but it's working now and I found that the encoding in eclipse is (Cp1252) which I don't understand what it means but this is not important now.